# C3DRendererContextSetupResidentMeshSourceAtLocation - double not supported in SceneKit

Tags: objective-c

I  am trying to rewrite this code for the iPhone:

https://github.com/d-ronnqvist/DRMeshGeometry

The code is working in the simulator, but the iPhone returns these errors:

```
2015-10-08 12:04:37.564 3dtest[4253:1581829] SceneKit: error, C3DRendererContextSetupResidentMeshSourceAtLocation - double not supported
2015-10-08 12:04:37.566 3dtest[4253:1581829] SceneKit: error, C3DSourceAccessorToVertexFormat - invalid vertex format
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Metal/Metal-54.31/Framework/MTLVertexDescriptor.mm:761: failed assertion `Unused buffer at index 18.'
```

The error is in this function:

```
- (SCNGeometry *)geometryWithFunction:(DRMeshFunction)function
    {
    self.function = function;

    NSUInteger width = self.stepsPerAxisCounts.one;
    NSUInteger depth = self.stepsPerAxisCounts.two;

    NSUInteger pointCount = width * depth;

    SCNVector3  vertices[pointCount];
    SCNVector3  normals[pointCount];
    CGPoint     textures[pointCount];


    NSUInteger numberOfIndices = (2*width)*(depth);
    if (depth%4==0) numberOfIndices += 2;

    short indices[numberOfIndices];


    short lastIndex = 0;
    for (int row = 0 ; row<width-1 ; row++) {
        BOOL isEven = row%2 == 0;
        for (int col = 0 ; col<depth ; col++) {

            if (isEven) {
                indices[lastIndex] = row*width + col;
                lastIndex++;
                indices[lastIndex] = (row+1)*width + col;
                if (col == depth-1) {
                    lastIndex++;
                    indices[lastIndex] = (row+1)*width + col;
                }
            } else {
                indices[lastIndex] = row*width + (depth-1-col);
                lastIndex++;
                indices[lastIndex] = (row+1)*width + (depth-1-col);
                if (col == depth-1) {
                    lastIndex++;
                    indices[lastIndex] = (row+1)*width + (depth-1-col);
                }
            }
            lastIndex++;
        }
    }

    // Generate the mesh by calculating the vector, normal
    // and texture coordinate for each x,z pair.
    for (int row = 0 ; row<width ; row++) {
        for (int col = 0 ; col<depth ; col++) {

            CGFloat one = (float)col/(width-1) * (self.rangeOne.max - self.rangeOne.min) + self.rangeOne.min;
            CGFloat two = (float)row/(depth-1) * (self.rangeTwo.max - self.rangeTwo.min) + self.rangeTwo.min;

            SCNVector3 value = [self vectorForFunction:function one:one two:two];

            vertices[col + row*depth] = value;

            CGFloat delta = 0.001;
            SCNVector3 dx = vectorSubtract(value,
                                           [self vectorForFunction:function one:one+delta two:two]);

            SCNVector3 dz = vectorSubtract(value,
                                           [self vectorForFunction:function one:one two:two+delta]);

            normals[col + row*depth] = normalize( crossProduct(dz, dx) );


            textures[col + row*depth] = CGPointMake(col/(float)width*self.textureRepeatCounts.one,
                                                    row/(float)depth*self.textureRepeatCounts.two);
        }
    }

    // Create geometry sources for the generated data

    SCNGeometrySource *vertexSource  = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithVertices:vertices           count:pointCount];
    SCNGeometrySource *normalSource  = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithNormals:normals             count:pointCount];
    SCNGeometrySource *textureSource = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithTextureCoordinates:textures count:pointCount];


    // Configure the indices that was to be interpreted as a
    // triangle strip using

    SCNGeometryElement *element =
    [SCNGeometryElement geometryElementWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:indices
                                                               length:sizeof(short[numberOfIndices])]
                                  primitiveType:SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeTriangleStrip
                                 primitiveCount:numberOfIndices
                                  bytesPerIndex:sizeof(short)];

    // Create geometry from these sources
    SCNGeometry *geometry = [SCNGeometry geometryWithSources:@[vertexSource, normalSource, textureSource]
                                                elements:@[element]];

    // Since the builder exposes a geometry with repeating texture 
    // coordinates it is configured with a repeating material

    SCNMaterial *repeatingTextureMaterial = [SCNMaterial material];
    repeatingTextureMaterial.doubleSided = YES;

    // Possibly repeat all the materials texture coordintes here
    repeatingTextureMaterial.specular.contents = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3 alpha:1.0];
    repeatingTextureMaterial.shininess = .1250;

    geometry.materials = @[repeatingTextureMaterial];

    return geometry;
}

I really do not know what to try
```

Answer (score 1):

I've a similar problem and I've found a workaround.

The error indicates that double isn't supported, and actually it's the Texture Coordinate who is using double values because of CGPoint.

So the solution is simple, create another struct to replace CGPoint, like the codes below.

Change

```
CGPoint textures[pointCount];
textures[col + row*depth] = CGPointMake(col/(float)width*self.textureRepeatCounts.one, row/(float)depth*self.textureRepeatCounts.two);
```

into

```
typedef struct FloatPoint {
    float x;
    float y;
} FloatPoint;

FloatPoint textures[pointCount];

textures[col + row*depth] = (FloatPoint){col/(float)width*self.textureRepeatCounts.one, row/(float)depth*self.textureRepeatCounts.two};
```

Change

```
SCNGeometrySource *textureSource = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithTextureCoordinates:textures count:pointCount];
```

into

```
SCNGeometrySource *textureSource = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:textures length:sizeof(textures)]
                                                                    semantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord
                                                                 vectorCount:pointCount
                                                             floatComponents:YES
                                                         componentsPerVector:2
                                                           bytesPerComponent:sizeof(float)
                                                                  dataOffset:offsetof(FloatPoint, x)
                                                                  dataStride:sizeof(FloatPoint)];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, it's:

```
let textureData = NSData(bytes: textCoords, length: textCoords.count * sizeof(FloatPoint.self))
let textSource = SCNGeometrySource(
  data: textureData as Data,
  semantic: SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord,
  vectorCount: textCoords.count,
  floatComponents: true,
  componentsPerVector: 2,
  bytesPerComponent: sizeof(Float.self),
  dataOffset: 0,
  dataStride: sizeof(FloatPoint.self)
)
```

(just set the offset to 0)